# How to store data of user using session

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know how to save the session data.
For it I have to create a mysql database or not
 and how to retrive the session data if logged in from somewhere 
I am using php and mysql

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about what you are asking.  If you are looking for a tutorial on how to use PHP sessions, SO is not the place for that.

Comment: Are you referring to the session storage in a browser or the act of creating sessions with php?

Comment: i want to store session data using php

Answer (score 0):

It may be a good idea to tell us where you are in your process so that we can help you better. But based on what I can get from your question, here is my suggestion.

You can add more variables to the global session variables $_SESSION[data_name] or/and store them in your database.

In the first instance, Here is a page that can help you get started: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp. The global variables including the ones you have added will be available as long as the user is logged in and you have not destroyed the session. Remember to destroy the session when the user logs out.

In the second instance, you can insert/update your session tables in the database with the global session variable including those that you have added above.
This needs a little more farmiliarity with mysql.
Here is a page that may help you:http://phpsecurity.org/code/ch08-2

Here is a general session reference page: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php